# unable to access server after changing permission AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, lamp

I accidentally changed the permission of home folder via SSH, now I am unable to access the files, please suggest me what to do, don't want to lose the files.

Comment: Do you have a root user, or access to the AWS console?

Comment: Yes have access to AWS console and have root user too

Comment: Can't you just use sudo to change the permissions back on the home folder.

Comment: I will be able to but the problem is now i am unable to connect to server itself, orelse i could have changed . Stuck with this

Answer (score 3):

If you've locked yourself out of an instance, you have two options to recover (assuming the data is on EBS - if it's on instance storage, you're out of luck)

Option #1 is to:

1. create a snapshot of the EBS volume
2. then, create a volume from the snapshot
3. launch a new EC2 instance using a key you have access to
4. associate the volume from step 2 with the instance in step 3
5. log into the instance and mount the volume
6. You now have access to the data

Option #2 is to fix the existing instance

1. Stop the bad instance
2. Disassociate the EBS volume from the stopped instance
3. launch a new EC2 instance using a key you have access to
4. Associate the volume with the instance you just created
5. log into the instance and mount the volume
6. Fix the permissions
7. Reverse the process: unmount, disassociate from new instance, re-associate with old instance, boot the old instance and you should be good.

Comment: I am a newbie to AWS and not have much idea about this, will i lose the changes i did?

Comment: Either of these options will give you access to the files on your original instance.

Comment: how to do the step 5, i mean how to mount the storage @chris